# javascript multidimensional array JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am grabbing data from a mySql DB via PHP and returning it to my javascript as JSON data. I want to stuff the returned data...the returned JSON data...into a javascript array:

```
var DataArray = new Array();

$.getJSON("php_src/getData.php?rTable="+myTable, function(data) {
    myData = data;

    $.each(myData , function(i,jsonData) {

        var bid = jsonData.user_id;
        $myBidFound = -1;
        for( $i=0; $i<DataArray.length; $i++ )
        {   
            if( DataArray[$i][0].user_id == bid )
            {
                $myBidFound = $i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if( $myBidFound == -1 )
        {
            $myBidFound = bid;
        }
        DataArray[$myBidFound] = new Array(jsonData);
    });
});
```

Is this the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

> and returning it to my javascript as JSON data

You don't have to do anything else then, just assign a variable to the received data. That's what JSON means.

`myData` should be what you want. Try to use it or log it to the console in a console-equipped browser (IE9, Fx, Chrome)

Comment: You are right `myData` IS what I want. BUT, I want to store this data so I can reference it later. The PHP is doing SQL call on the database and returning data from 3 tables as 1 record...potentially a lot of records (~300 or so).

Comment: I am also doing some jQuery stuff with each data item, cloning a `div` and inserting the new `div` in the DOM, once I get the data back from the PHP.

Comment: `BUT, I want to store this data so I can reference it later.` so you want like a page-global variable that the various methods can access? Or do you want to use the browser's localstorage if it's available?

Comment: `I am also doing some jQuery stuff with each data item,` has nothing to do with the rest of the problem. I do that all the time. Then I call the jQuery .data() function and attach the data I used to create the row to the row on insert into my tables. Then I can iterate over each table and get the JSON object back from the .data function.

Comment: I am using a global variable defined in 'common.js' that all the methods can access... In the example, `var DataArray...` is defined in my 'common.js'.

Comment: **OUCH** Just trying to explain what I want to do. Not everyone in the world is an expert, some of us have to break things down to a lower level to get a good grasp on the subject. That was not a helpful comment at all...

Comment: And so far you haven't done a good job with the narrative Sam. I'm trying to help, and I offered what I thought you needed, including a comment for debugging. I thought we were on the same page, then you went left when I was going straight. Start over with a narrative and maybe even a sample of the data.

Comment: My JSON data contains `user_id, upload_time, user_latitude, user_longitude`. It is sorted by the `user_id` when returned via PHP. I want to create a 2 dimensional array where the first level, `DataArray[x]`, is referenced by the user_id and the second level, `DataArary[user_id][y]` contains the data. Later, I can loop through all the data for a particular `user_id`...or grab the and location data for all users at a specific `upload_time`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cache the results on the client side, try using `$.Data()` method. It will store the results in the DOM.

I have done it before with the toolTip and it seemed to work nicely.